# Selenium - Difficulty finding input element on page (Python)

Tags: python, selenium

I am having trouble finding a search bar on a webpage that I am trying to automate. I have tried a couple approaches but being rather new to selenium, I am not sure what more advanced locating options there are.

Breakdown::
The following is an section of code with the search bar element (corresponding to input) being highlighted

[The xpath to the following highlighted section is below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zsu6g.png):

```
//*[@id='core-content-container']/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/nav/div/div[2]/form/ul/li[1]/input
```

When I try to find this element via find_element_by_xpath however, I get a `NoSuchElementException` (I have tried shorter xpaths but those provided the same error)

Below is the relevant code bit I am using to try to find this element:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()

#DNSMgr
driver.get('https://barista.cac.washington.edu/dnsmgr/#/fqdn')

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='core-content-container']/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/nav/div/div[2]/form/ul/li[1]/input")
```

Since the exact line that I am trying to get at looks like this:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" ng-model="query" placeholder="Full domain name">
```

I then thought that maybe I could get at the element by using

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('input.form-control.ng-pristine.ng-untouched.ng-valid')
```

Since this is similar to the example on seleniums python tutorials in section 4.7 I thought that could do the job but that also doesn't work (I get another `NoSuchElementException`).

Comment: Try printing the driver's contents - are you sure you're searching the same page that's in your browser? I get redirected to a login page when I click your link, is selenium actively logging in prior to getting that page?

Comment: I have found that sometimes before a page loads completely, selenium tries to execute the next statement in my code. If you import the time library (standard on python) and do a time.sleep(2) (waits 2 seconds) after any navigation command, it will sometimes prevent these errors. I am assuming speed is not that big a deal since you are using selenium? @Saurabh Gaur provides some insight to what im kinda talking about.

Comment: @DanielleM. on my side I've automated the login so I don't get that page, you would have to be a UW student or faculty member to actually see the page that I am working on unfortunately

Comment: @BLang thanks, I will definitely explore that option. considered it but didn't know how to implement it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are getting `NoSuchElementException` as your provided exception, There could be following reasons :-

- May be when you are going to find element, it would not be present on the `DOM`, So you should implement [`Explicit wait`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits) using `WebDriverWait` to wait until element is present as below :-

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div#core-content-container input.form-control[ng-model='query'][placeholder='Full domain name']")))
  ```
- May be this element is inside any `frame` or `iframe`. If it is, you need to switch that `frame` or `iframe` before finding the element as below :-

  ```
   wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

  #Find frame or iframe and switch
  wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it(("frame/iframe id or name")))

  #Now find the element 
  element = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div#core-content-container input.form-control[ng-model='query'][placeholder='Full domain name']")))

  #Once all your stuff done with this frame need to switch back to default
  driver.switch_to_default_content()
  ```